# Descargar de manera sincrona un archivo csv

Tags: c#

He querido descargar un archivo csv de manera asincrona pero no lo quiere descargar, le he calado con otros links de descarga y si hace la descarga pero con el que quiero descargar no funciona 
esta es la url"https://smn.cna.gob.mx/tools/PHP/sivea/siveaEsri2/php/manejador_descargas_csv_estaciones.php?estacion=CIUDADMANTE&organismo=SMN&variable=temperatura%27&fbclid=IwAR3lT8srywft8Sy7OVAHDQ9_6ePUYm-am6ZzcN-zSsdCOVxGGMy0aa_guDQ"

```
public void descarcasincrona(String url)
    {
       WebClient cliente = new WebClient();
        cliente.Proxy = null;
        cliente.DownloadFile( url, "C:\\DATOS_ATMOSFERICOS\\datos2019.csv");

    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Muy probablemente porque no es un archivo, es un proceso que devuelve un archivo...

Answer (score 1):

Sucede que las llamadas asíncronas no bloquean el hilo (Thread) principal, partamos en que el método `DownloadFileAsync` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196(v=vs.110).aspx) retorna inmediatamente pasando a la siguiente línea, causando que el método `DescargAsincrona` también se retorne inmediatamente. Esto hace que el programa termine sin que haya descargado nada (Esto pasa en tu código original).

Tendrías que bloquear el hilo principal hasta que haya finalizado la descarga. Has considerado el uso de `async/await` que está disponible en el Framework .NET 4.5 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)? Podrías usar los eventos `Progress/Completed` para sincronizar tu método lo que haría que tu aplicación no cierre hasta que hayas descargado el archivo.

Extendí un poco el código para que se entienda mejor y soporte el bloqueo del hilo principal. Esto hará esperar al hilo principal 1 Seg hasta que verifique nuevamente si se ha completado la descarga. Uso la palabra clave `"volatile"` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx) para asegurarme de que el nuevo valor siempre se almacene. Esto es importante para aplicaciones multi hilos (multi threading). La variable `_completed = true` está afuera del if/else porque necesitamos que finalice incluso si cancelamos la descarga. Puedes extender el código en caso de que quieras verificar si se ha cancelado la descarga.

Abajo te dejo el código:

```
public class DownloadGamefile
{
    private volatile bool _completed;

    public void DescargAsincrona(string address, string location)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri(address);
        _completed = false;

        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);

        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgress);
        client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, location);

    }

    public bool DownloadCompleted { get { return _completed; } }

    private void DownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Displays the operation identifier, and the transfer progress.
        Console.WriteLine("{0}    downloaded {1} of {2} bytes. {3} % complete...",
            (string)e.UserState,
            e.BytesReceived,
            e.TotalBytesToReceive,
            e.ProgressPercentage);
    }

    private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Download has been canceled.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
        }

        _completed = true;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        DownloadGamefile DGF = new DownloadGamefile();

        DGF.DescargAsincrona("https://smn.cna.gob.mx/tools/PHP/sivea/siveaEsri2/php/manejador_descargas_csv_estaciones.php?estacion=CIUDADMANTE&organismo=SMN&variable=temperatura%27&fbclid=IwAR3lT8srywft8Sy7OVAHDQ9_6ePUYm-am6ZzcN-zSsdCOVxGGMy0aa_guDQ", @"C:\\DATOS_ATMOSFERICOS\\datos2019.csv");

        while (!DGF.DownloadCompleted)
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva

Saludos